# Java networking program; (Lagging issue)

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp

I made a real- time game, and it is extremely laggy right now.
I saw that for real time game I have write codes with 'UDP protocol', instead of 'TCP'

Would this solve the lagging problem? and would it be really hard to change my code in 'UDP' form?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you `.flush()` the sockets you `.write()` to?

Answer (score 0):

1. ***Would this solve the lagging problem?***

   UDP protocol is a little bit faster than TCP, because it lacks a couple of value-adding extras:

   - It's unreliable - it doesn't check whether packets arrive successfully.  If there's a network problem a packet can be lost.
   - Also it doesn't guarantee whether packets arrive in order.

   These give a small additional lag when all is well (extra handshake messages required to confirm correct delivery) and a bigger lag when there are errors on the network (extra retry packets, receiver waiting/reordering).
   For a game, you mightn't need these extra services.

   Would you definitely notice the difference?  Not necessarily.

   The speed, traffic load and number of network router/switch hops of the underlying network has a large effect on individual packet performance.  You might not notice any difference within a gigabit local LAN, but might see a small difference across wireless and a big difference across the internet.  Bad router setup and busy network would obviously make things worse.

   To understand your network path and to check the speed & reliability/errors on your network, use

   - command-line `ping` & `traceroute`/`tracert`
   - a network checking tool, e.g. [LAN Speed Test](http://download.cnet.com/LAN-Speed-Test/3000-2085_4-10908738.html) or [NetStatLive](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/nsl.htm) or [testmy.net](http://testmy.net/)

   See also [How Fast Is Your Network?](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-basics/31220-how-fast-is-your-network-five-ways-to-measure-network-speed)
2. ***Would it be really hard to change my code in 'UDP' form?***

   No.

   Instead of using `java.net.Socket`, and j`ava.net.ServerSocket` use `java.net.DatagramSocket` x 2.

   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html